# How to Get Gameobject position on screen resolution that not passed the resolution to set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an object at the screen. At the beginning it is located at x=0,y=0,z=0 later it moves to a different position. I just want to make sure that this object does not move to locations invisible to the user (it's the player main character itself and I neither want the player to be able to go back from his current location nor going forward the camera following him).

Can you explain to me what I need to do here?

Comment: i am sorrry for the poor english here what i try to do like the game super mario that if he advance the camera going with him if he try go back then he can go back but just where the the screen and and there no passed from where he passed

Comment: I think, you mean, you want a 2d character how can only goes i.e. to the right side of the screen, and he can never return back to the places it visited before on the left side of the screen. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I **think** you're asking:

If a player-character on the screen is moving around, you want the person sitting at the computer to be able to see it always.  To do this you need to set up the camera to follow this object.

Here are some links that may get you started:

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-Camera.html

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial has an example of how to implement a camera that follows the player.

http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/3d-platform-game.html

Comment: the game is 2d how much that helps here?

Comment: Here's one in 2D: http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/2d-gameplay-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewGameScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float t=0f;
    float v=20f;
    float dist;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    void Update () 
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyUp("up"))
        {
            if(t<0.1)
            {
                t +=Time.deltaTime*0.07f;
            }
            dist=t*v*0.5f;
            gameObject.transform.position +=transform.forward*dist;                   
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyUp("down"))
        {
            if(t>-0.1)
            {
                t -=Time.deltaTime*0.07f;
            }
            dist=t*v*0.5f;
            gameObject.transform.position +=transform.forward*dist;
        }   
        else if(Input.GetKey("left"))
        {   
            transform.Rotate(0,-0.9f*(dist+1), 0);
            gameObject.transform.position +=transform.forward*0.1f*(dist+1);
        }   
        else if(Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            transform.Rotate( 0,0.9f*(dist+1),0);
            gameObject.transform.position +=transform.forward*0.1f*(dist+1);
        }
    }
}
```